# YouTube Live Streaming API Request With Api Key

Tags: authentication, youtube-api, google-oauth

I am working with youtube live streaming API services and as described here,

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/registering_an_application#create_project

I'd like yo use API keys, rather than OAuth 2.0 for communication. But when I'm requesting

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id&broadcastStatus=all&key=[My_App_Key]

I always end up with

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Any ideas why I'm forced to use OAuth and can't operate with API Key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LiveBroadcasts: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) states at the top that

> Authorization
>
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following
>   scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication)).

You cant use a public API key with this method you must be authenticated using oauth2.

Comment: Thanks for response, looks like OAuth is the only way. Thanks.